# Strange pulse with N-MOSFET switching Raspberry Pi power supply

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi, pulse

My schematic is as follows:

[image]

5 volts coming from a lab power supply (10 amperes.)

Looking at the voltage input with an oscilloscope, I see this:

[image]

A strange pulse going up to 5.08 volts every 500 ms, but sometimes the period seems to change randomly.

I tried replacing the Raspberry Pi wiith a 10 ohms charge resistor and saw no problem. How I can explain this phenomenon?

I made a zoom of the scope the baseline is around 4,70 volts (which is the normal Voltage when Rpi is on) the spike goes to 5,08 Volts (my power supply show 5,2 volts)

[image]

Comment: Is that a single channel oscilloscope? Without knowing the current, I would think that the voltage increases when switching off, which are caused by line inductances.

Comment: I don't know why you have a negative voltage at the top, probably means mosfet is always conducting. Is there an LED blinking somewhere?

Comment: The only led blinking are on RPI,

Comment: The schematic diagram shows -5V in the top right corner. I assume that should be +5 V, right?

Comment: "Looking at the voltage input with an oscilloscope". Please clarify what you mean by "voltage input". Where on that schematic is that "voltage input"?

Comment: Yes of course it +5V , when reducing the image it goes to minus sign, the voltage input means the power supply of the RPI +5V and GND connected on the I/O connector (Not USB powered)

Comment: Is the supply under such little load it's going into some burst mode?

Comment: I do not think is the power supply issue, I tested with 10 Ohms charge resistance and there is no problem, signal on scope stay flat.

Comment: Firstly, its bad juju to switch the negative - why? High potential for ‘sneak’ circuits back via other nodes like USB and anything else connected to the Pi. It will bite you when you least expect it to.  What do you measure without the mosfet in circuit? And don’t be fooled by your 10Ohm resistor test - this is a complex system and the Pi load is far from a simple resistor.

Comment: This a complex system where I have 2 power supply 12V and 5V with common ground to switch at low cost , and there are nothing connected externally to RPI. I know it is not perfect to switch common ground, but it does not explain these burst.

Comment: Please don’t switch the negative side of your supply. You are asking for problems.